# How can I get all player data using the ESPN V3 fantasy basketball API?

Tags: api, espn

I found the API to get player data for my league.
http://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/fba/seasons/2021/segments/0/leagues/?view=kona_player_info

However this only gets me the first 50 players. Does anyone know how I could get the rest? Is there some way to get them by last name letter?

Any help or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats the league id? This url doesnt return anything

Comment: also, what's the url (not the api url) and what data are you trying to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They started using a custom request header **x-fantasy-filter** to give context to the results from API calls like: https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/flb/seasons/2021/segments/0/leaguedefaults/1?scoringPeriodId=0&view=kona_player_info which is called from stat pages like https://fantasy.espn.com/baseball/players/projections.

Examine the header in your debugger and see if it looks similar to the one below.

Two obvious values are **limit** and **offset**. These are for pagination, give me 50 records, starting at the 50th record from the start gives you records 51-100.

It sounds like you might want to try out the **sortDraftRanks** to sort to specific records, but I haven't played with that yet.

```
{
"players":
  {
    "filterStatsForExternalIds": {"value":[2020,2021]},
    "filterSlotIds":{"value":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,19]},
    "filterStatsForSourceIds":{"value":[0,1]},
    "useFullProjectionTable":{"value":true},
    "sortAppliedStatTotal":{"sortAsc":false,"sortPriority":2,"value":"102021"},
    "sortDraftRanks":{"sortPriority":3,"sortAsc":true,"value":"STANDARD"},
    "sortPercOwned":{"sortPriority":4,"sortAsc":false},
    "limit":50,
    "offset":50,
    "filterStatsForTopScoringPeriodIds":{
      "value":5,
      "additionalValue":["002021","102021","002020","012021","022021","032021","042021","010002021"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!