# Get all ESPN Fantasy Basketball player statistics (more than 50) in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, espn

I joined a public ESPN Fantasy Basketball league and I would like to connect an Excel worksheet to the ESPN Fantasy API (currently V3) to download on-demand the players statistics available through this API URL: [kona_player_info](https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/fba/seasons/2023/segments/0/leaguedefaults/2?view=kona_player_info).
I was able to connect through Power Query to that URL, navigate records, select the ones I am interested in and output the columns to a worksheet.
The problem is that only **50 players** are being shown. Infact, the daily leaders statistics are paginated by 50 players.
I read some posts here and there, for instance: [How can I get all player data using the ESPN V3 fantasy basketball API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414912/how-can-i-get-all-player-data-using-the-espn-v3-fantasy-basketball-api)
and understood it is all related to the custom request header "x-fantasy-filter".
What I don't know is how to implement this in the Excel connection. Everything I have read so far about the header x-fantasy-filter looks like addressable in python language or so.

Do you have any clue how to get in Excel the full list of players statistics (they are about 1K)?

[image: custom header with player count: 972]

Comment: what url are you using in the power query

Comment: https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/fba/seasons/2023/segments/0/leaguedefaults/2?view=kona_player_info